# Converting Data type of a specific column of an uploaded data in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have uploaded a data.frame and have also obtained from the user the name of the column whose datatype needs to be changed to factor using R shiny. I am not able to convert user specific column to the specific data type. How do I do it? Also how do I check if the column has been converted to the desired data type?

Answer (score 0):

Im also not sure what you exactly want, but maybe this code-snippet can help you:

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(
  rep(1, 10),
  rep("1", 10),
  rep("a", 10)
))
colnames(df) <- c("col1","col2","col3")
str(df)
```

This will create a data.frame, where all columns are factors.
To change the type of a column, you just change it :)

```
df$col1 <- as.numeric(df$col1)
df$col3 <- as.character(df$col3)
str(df)
```

This will change the first column to numeric values and the last one to characters.

To change the first column back to factors you would use:

```
df$col1 <-as.factor(df$col1)
str(df)
```

And to test whether a column is factor you can use:

```
is.factor(df$col1)
```

Comment: Hi  Thanks for replying back to my query. In

Answer (score 0):

**I figured out the solution to the problem.**
Let me rephrase my question, I have a data frame (df) with three columns named as col1, col2 and col3. Here is the challenge that I was facing, I am getting the column name from the user ***(R shiny interface)*** as character vector and assigning it to the variable say
 
                                                            **MyCol <- "col1"** 
Now I want to **convert the data type of col1** in my data frame (df)  to factor **(i.e col1 datatype as.factor)**.
 
When I perform the function 
                                                   **df$MyCol <- as.factor(df$MyCol)**
  I get error, 
however I figured it out that I need to do this for converting the data type of my column
                                                   **df[ , MyCol] <- as.factor[ , MyCol]**

**This worked for me. :-)**